# PHP: Conditional based on date

Tags: php, date

I have a date like this: 16/02/2011

What I want to do is have a simple PHP conditional that checks if todays date is either that DAY or AFTER so for example:

```
<?php

    $mydate = '26/01/2010';

    if($mydate == date('dd/mm/yyyy')
    {
        echo 'last day to reply';
    }
    elseif($mydate == 'date after todays date')
    {
        echo 'post has expired and you cannot reply';

    }
    else
    {
        echo 'post has NOT expired and you can reply';
    }

?>
```

So if today's date is 01/01/2011 then it would say post has not expired
if date is 17/02/2011 then it would say last day to reply
and if the date is after 25/02/2011 then it would say it has expired.

Can anyone help? Thanks :)

Comment: I don't understand your example dates - how can 17/02/2011 be the last day? Is the deadline the 18th or the 16th?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mktime` (or `strotime` if you can get your end date in a proper format, 17-02-2011 or 02/17/2011):

```
$mydate = '17/02/2011';
$mydate_parts = explode('/', $mydate);
$mydate_timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $mydate_parts[1], $mydate_parts[0], $mydate_parts[2]);

if($mydate == date('d/m/Y'))
{
    echo 'last day to reply';
}
elseif($mydate_timestamp < time())
{
    echo 'post has expired and you cannot reply';

}
else
{
    echo 'post has NOT expired and you can reply';
}
```

Comment: If they are one second after the deadline day, they cannot reply!  You can also use `strtotime()` instead of `mktime()` here..doesn't matter much though.  I think you also mean > `time()`?

Comment: @tandu err, if today is 17/02/2011, then it will print 'last day'. If timestamp is less than current time, then it's expired, otherwise they can reply. And `strtotime` doesn't understand d/m/Y format, had to use `mktime`

Comment: Ah, good call, sorry.  I still think you mean > time(), though.

Comment: @tandu no, I meant `<`. 17.02.2011 < 18.02.2011 so the post IS expired

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @meze! This really helped me for my project. I used the conditional to add php headers for soon-to-expire domains.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use [mktime](http://www.php.net/mktime) to convert the required date and times (the last date and the ultimate deadline) and then directly compare the current [time](http://www.php.net/time) against the those.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to have a date already in the proper format. Especially if it's coming from database.

```
<?php

    $mydate = '2010-01-26';
    $curdate = date('Y-m-d');

    if($curdate == $mydate)
    {
        echo 'last day to reply';
    }
    elseif($curdate > $mydate)
    {
        echo 'post has expired and you cannot reply';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'post has NOT expired and you can reply';
    }

?>
```

note that by reading this code you will have no problem understanding what does it do.
it's almost natural language and self-explanatory
unlike all other codes here.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than compare visual dates it's probably better to compare timestamps:

```
$deadline = strtotime('2010-01-26');
$today = mktime(0, 0, 0);
if ($today == $deadline) {
   echo 'last day';
}
else if ($today > $deadline) {
   echo 'past day';
}
else {
   echo 'a-okay';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In simplistic terms, you'd want to do somethinn like:

if (strtotime($date) > date()) {
   echo "Your post has expired";
}

it's very difficult to compare dates-that-are-strings, especially when you consider that "2/3/4" could be any of 8 different dates (Feb 3rd, '04; Mar 4th, '02; etc..). Keeping dates/times as actual timestamp values in PHP makes the comparisons far easier.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you look up on the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class documentation; if you're not interested though; a [string slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) would work.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of the following is probably the quickest for you.

```
if( mktime(0,0,0,substr($mydate, 3, 2), substr($mydate, 0, 2), substr($mydate, 6, 4) ) > time() )
```